# Подскажите пожалуйста ,что не так с JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch

```
window.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{
 if(event.target.hasAttribute('data-cart')){
  const card = event.target.closest('.card');

  const cardInfo = {
   id: card.dataset.id,
   counter: card.querySelector('.control-info').innerText
  }

  
 let local = localStorage.getItem('cart');
  if(local !== null){
    local = JSON.parse(local);
  } else local = [];
  local.push(cardInfo);
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(local));

  
  fetch('http://shop/corzina.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: localStorage.getItem('cart'),
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)

  })

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
 $out = json_decode($_POST , true);
 print_r($out);
```

В итоге получаю ошибку, хотя онлайн декодер нормально преобразует в массив!

```
 <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\OpenServer\domains\shop\corzina.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

Comment: А ты переведи в переводчике фразу.......не стесняйся

Comment: Вы вместо того, чтобы отдать функции строку с кодированным json, отдаете ей весь массив `$_POST`. Выведите через `var_dump` переменную `$_POST` и посмотрите какого она типа и что она в себе содержит

Comment: @rusgeli array(1) {
  ["""]=>
  array(1) {
    ["{\"id\":\"3\",\"counter\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"counter\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"counter\":\"1\"}"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
} Подскажите что из этого брать тогда?